# How to modify data cursor value in Lightning Chart - ViewXY?

Tags: c#, charts, lightningchart, lineseries

I am using DataCursorXY to show the values of the X and Y axes. However, when I move the mouse over the line series, the X-axis value inside the cursor table doesn't match the X-axis label time format.[The X axis label time format is (HH:mm:ss) but the cursor's time format is (AM: Time).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljuy6.png)

How do I change the time format inside the data cursor into hour:minute:second? I would like to use the existing DataCursorXY if possible.